How to disable ui5plugin-linter?
in VSCode have installed the SAPUI5 Extension, its nice because it gives me autocompletion, however, the ui5plugin-linter is also enabled in the extension. I would like to disable the linter completely. I already tried to put a .eslintignore with **/* to ignore everything, but it did not work.. do I have to install the vscode eslint extension also to disable it?
I have no idea how to make eslint for ui5 not work...
